# Safely Get Tail of Array

Tags: scala

I called `tail` on an `Array`, but saw a warning.

```
scala> val arr = Array(1,2)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)

scala> arr tail
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res3: Array[Int] = Array(2)
```

Scaladocs for [Array](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) shows an `UnsupportedOperationException [will be thrown]
if the mutable indexed sequence is empty.`

Is there a safe, won't throw exception, way to get the tail of an array?

Answer (score 14):

> Is there a safe, won't throw exception, way to get the tail of an
>   array?

You can use `drop`:

```
scala> Array(1, 2, 3).drop(1)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(2, 3)

scala> Array[Int]().drop(1)
res1: Array[Int] = Array()
```

Also note that as mentioned by [@TravisBrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647874/safely-get-tail-of-array/18648370?noredirect=1#comment27459065_18648370) in the comment below, `drop` doesn't differentiate between an empty tail (for collections with one element) and the absence of tail (for empty collections) since in both the cases, `drop(1)` would return an empty collection.

Comment: This also throws away information, in the sense that `Array(1).drop(1) sameElements Array.empty[Int].drop(1)`.

Comment: Don't see your point. Array.empty[String] sameElements Array.empty[Int].

Comment: @TravisBrown I also don't get it. Can you please explain?

Comment: +1 Should be the accepted answer imho. Btw, I think what Travis Brown meant is simple: by doing that, one cannot distinguish between empty and 1-length source lists, since both will return an empty tail. Still, I believe this is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: The OP asked about `tail`. The tail of an empty collection is _not_ the empty collection—it's some kind of undefined thing. This answer also doesn't address the fact that the warning is about syntax and has nothing to do with `tail` specifically.

Comment: @TravisBrown, isn't the tail of an empty collection well-defined - an exception: `scala> List().tail --->
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list`

Comment: This answer does give the tail of an array in a safe way, doesn't it? You are right about the empty collection part and your answer perfectly explains about the warning so I left it out and quoted the part of the question I was answering. I agree your answer is better but I don't think this answer deserves a downvote (from you, I guess).

Comment: @MarimuthuMadasamy: `drop(1)` simply isn't the same as `tail`. In fact you _can't_ write a safe `tail` without reifying the undefined case somehow (e.g. with `Option`). I don't mean the downvote as an insult or a personal attack, of course—I just find this answer inaccurate, and that's what voting is for.

Comment: @Kevin: I mean undefined in the sense that the mathematical functions head and tail are partial: they aren't defined on empty lists. The exception is just how Scala has decided to crash when we try to apply its implementation of these functions to something they can't be applied to.

Comment: "drop(1) simply isn't the same as tail" - I agree. "I don't mean the downvote as an insult or a personal attack, of course" - None taken, no worries. :)

Comment: @MarimuthuMadasamy: And I'd of course be more than happy to remove the downvote if you edit the language to note the difference.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the warning doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you're using an unsafe method. If you restart the REPL with `-feature` you'll see the following:

```
scala> arr tail
<console>:9: warning: postfix operator tail should be enabled
by making the implicit value language.postfixOps visible...
```

And a pointer to [the documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.language$) for `scala.language.postfixOps`, which includes the following note:

> Postfix operators interact poorly with semicolon inference. Most programmers avoid them for this reason.

This is good advice. Being able to write `arr tail` instead of `arr.tail` isn't worth the fuss.

Now about the safety issue. The standard library doesn't provide a `tailOption` for collections, but you can get the same effect using `headOption` and `map`:

```
scala> val arr = Array(1, 2)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)

scala> arr.headOption.map(_ => arr.tail)
res0: Option[Array[Int]] = Some([I@359be9fb)
```

If this is too verbose or opaque or inefficient for you, you can easily create an implicit class that would add a nicer `tailOption` to `Array` (or `Seq`, or `IndexedSeq`, etc.).

Comment: I really wish scalac would just enable feature warnings by default. What does hiding them accomplish?

Comment: @ChristopherMartin: Agreed! And while we're at it we could wish for warnings for unsafe methods like `tail`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Weakly checked exceptions?

Comment: @TravisBrown is there any particular reason for you to avoid using a `Try` here?

Comment: @NicolasRinaudo: In my mind `Try` is for exception handling, and there's nothing exceptional about an empty collection. So sure, it'd work, but feels a little wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

See @TravisBrown's answer for the reason of your warning.

I would personally use a `scala.util.Try` rather than his rather clever map on the array's head:

```
scala> val arr = Array(0, 1, 2)
arr: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2)

scala> scala.util.Try {arr.tail} foreach {t => println(t.mkString(","))}
1,2
```